# How to correctly close a tk.Toplevel that includes a matplotlib animation chart inside

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, tkinter, toplevel

I have created a Tkinter GUI that when a button is pushed, creates a tk.Toplevel. This tk.Toplevel includes a matplotlib animated chart that is inserted as a tk widget. **My problem is that when I close the tk.Toplevel and I push the button to create another tk.Toplevel, a matplotlib figure is generated apart from the desired tk.Toplevel**.
I have tried using 'WM_DELETE_WINDOW' tk.Toplevel closing protocol and do:

```
plt.close()
tk.Toplevel.destroy()
```

But doing this both the main GUI and the tk.Toplevel were closed.

The next lines of code represent a simplification of what I have reached with my program:

```
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.figure as mf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as ani
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import numpy as np

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack()
        frame = MAININTERFACE(parent=container, controller=self)
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
    def graph(self):
        grafica1=GRAPHICATION(controller=self)
        grafica1.Graph()

class MAININTERFACE(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        self.button=tk.Button(self, text='GRAPH', command=lambda: self.controller.graph())
        self.button.pack(pady=20)

class GRAPHICATION(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self)
        self.controller=controller
        self.x=[]
        self.y=[]
    def animation_frame(self, i):
        if i==0.0:
            self.time=0
            self.energy=0
        else:
            self.time=self.time+1
            self.energy=self.energy+1
        self.x.append(self.time)
        self.y.append(self.energy)
        self.line.set_data(self.x,self.y)
        self.ax.axis([0,10,0,10])

    def Graph(self):
        self.graphtoplevel=tk.Toplevel(self.controller)
        self.graphtoplevel.title('Toplevel')
        self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots()
        self.graph=FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, self.graphtoplevel)
        self.image=self.graph.get_tk_widget()
        plt.ion()
        self.line, = self.ax.plot(self.x,self.y)
        self.image.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
        self.animation=FuncAnimation(self.fig,func=self.animation_frame,frames=np.arange(0,11,1),interval=500, repeat=False)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.geometry('500x200')
    app.title('MAIN GUI')
    app.mainloop()
```

Hope that my question is understood. Thank you.

Comment: Removing `plt.ion()` does the job.

Comment: Thank you @JacksonPro, I can't remove `plt.ion()` because I need it for some other stuff but still worked by doing `plt.ioff()` when closing the tk.Toplevel.

Comment: Well, then you can post that as an answer.

Comment: Is there another way of doing that apart from removing `plt.ion()` or adding `plt.ioff()`at the end?

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be solved by deleting `plt.ion()` or doing `plt.ioff()` when closing the tk.Toplevel.